# Collapsible tableview section for static cells in swift 3

Tags: tableview, swift3, xcode8

I have created a sidebar using static table view having 2 sections. I created this using storyboard only. I want to have the sections collapsible. I found this resource in github

https://github.com/jeantimex/ios-swift-collapsible-table-section

But they have made a collapsible tableview section without any storyboard and for dynamic cells. I can't figure out how to do this. Any help would be highly appreciated.